# Redirect management.call_command() stdout to a file

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to redirect the standard output of a custom django command using this piece of code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core import management


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        f = open('/tmp/output', 'r+')
        management.call_command('basequery', 'list', 'log', stdout=f)
        f.close()
```

However, when I call this from manage.py the standard output appears on the console and the /tmp/output file is created but empty.

Here's the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#output-redirection) of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I'm guessing maybe because `open('/tmp/output', 'r+')` opens the file for _reading_ only, but you need to be able to write to it

Comment: @Anentropic 'r+' means read and write. I already tried with 'w' and I get the same result

Comment: oops, you are correct! :)

Comment: If you're only using this new management command to call another that writes it's output to a file, you could just pipe the results to a file on the command line.

Comment: @schillingt I'm using this new management command to trigger multiple django commands and capture their stdout and stderr to calculate metrics.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your command is probably just using `print` directly.  To be able to capture or redirect prints in a management command, you'll want to use the `self.stdout` handle of the command instance:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # incorrect way to print in a management command:
        print('This line will go to the terminal')

        # correct ways to print in a management command:
        print('This line will go into the StringIO', file=self.stdout)
        self.stdout.write('This will also go into the StringIO')
```

If you're unable change the print calls within the command (which is the code within `'basequery'` in your example), then you can use a context manager to temporarily redirect stdout in order to capture that output. It's important to restore the old stdout after redirection.  See [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

Answer (score 8):

If you have control over the code of the management command, then you should follow the answer by @wim. This answer assumes you can't/won't change the command itself.

The method by @Igor is the best way when available, but some commands ignore `stdout` argument.

@Phob1a has a solution that is basically okay but has the problem of closing `stdout` (so future output to it doesn't work). With some changes:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
import sys

stdout_backup, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, open('output_file', 'w+')
call_command('your_command')
sys.stdout = stdout_backup
```

Note that if you want to just throw away output, you should replace the first command:

```
from os import devnull
stdout_backup, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, open(devnull, 'a')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to redirect output to file

```
    f = open('/path/to/file', 'w')
    buf = StringIO()
    call_command('compile_game_data', 'kingdom', indent=4, stdout=buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    f.write(buf.read())
    f.close()
```

Comment: I've tried your method but I get the same result. The command line keeps printing the stdout and the StringIO .read() method after doing .seek(0) is returning nothing. The same result as passing stdout=f.

Comment: Can you provide actual code that you use with StringIO?

Comment: sure. I posted it as an answer below.

Comment: This doesn't work if the command defines its own stdout parameter.

Answer (score -2):

I tried Igor's approximation using the following code:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        f = open('/tmp/output', 'w+')
        out = StringIO()
        management.call_command('basequery', 'list', 'log', stdout=out)
        out.seek(0)
        f.write(out.read())
        f.close()
```

I got the same result tough: empty file and stdout appearing in the console. Maybe that's because I'm calling django commands from a django command?

Anyway, I managed to solve the problem this way:

```
    sys.stdout = open('/tmp/output', 'w+')
    management.call_command('basequery', 'list', 'log')
    sys.stdout.close()
```

I know it is an ugly solution but it's the only way I made it work.

Comment: This breaks stdout, if you print anything after this code you get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: couldn't it be fixed by saving `sys.stdout` to a temporary variable and restoring it after?